How to Prove following Weighted Forest Problem is NP-hard?
I am studying the following Weighted Forest Problem, which is an optimization problem in graph theory focused on finding optimal forest structures in robust scenarios. The problem is defined as follows:
Given an undirected graph $G = (V, E, w)$, where $V$ is the set of vertices, $E$ is the set of edges, and $w: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ represents the edge weights. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of all forests over $G$. The goal is to find a first-stage solution $S \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ that maximizes the following:
$$
\max_{S \in \mathcal{F}} \min_{D \subseteq E, |D| \leq k} \max_{R \subseteq E \setminus D, |R| \leq \ell} w((S \cup R) \setminus D)
$$
Here, $D$ is the set of edges removed by an adversary, and $R$ is the set of edges re-added after removal.
So the problem consists of two stages:

Stage One: You choose a forest $ S $.
Stage Two:

An adversary can remove up to $ k$ edges from your chosen forest. The set of removed edges is denoted by $ D $.
You can then re-add up to $ \ell $ edges from the remaining edges in the graph. The set of re-added edges is denoted by $ R $.
The final forest you end up with is $ (S \cup R) \setminus D $, and its total weight is $ w((S \cup R) \setminus D) $.



Your goal in the first stage is to choose a forest $ S $ such that, after the adversary’s worst-case removal and your subsequent recovery action, the weight of the final forest is as large as possible.
I would like to know if this problem is NP-hard. If so, could you please explain in detail how to prove that it is NP-hard or suggest some related reduction methods?
This figure is an example for k=2, l=1. The solid edge is the first stage solution and the red color edge is D. This example does not have R. And I would also like to know if this k=2, l=1 version problem is np-hard or not.


How is the weight calculated for a given set of edges? Just the sum of individual edge weights? In that case it seems you can change "forest" to "induced $P_2$ subgraph" in the problem description retaining its complexity. But it seems the problem is too trivial if so.

The reason I use forests is to avoid connectivity that can't be guaranteed after $D$ is removed. In the vast majority of cases the first stage solution is necessarily a spanning tree. One can start by considering the case k=2, l=1, in which case I did not find a polynomial time algorithm.

Is there a limit on the size of the forest $S$ you choose in the beginning? It seems that nothing stops us from choosing a forest that contains all edges of the maximum spanning forest with $\ell$ heaviest edges removed.

But thats not 100% optimal solution, pls check the figure,  the best solution 5-3-3 is a normal spanningtree.

As far as I understand, the player has chosen the tree {AD, AB, BC} on the first move. By the problem specification, the opponent can't remove the edge CD, because it does not belong to the chosen forest.

Then there also is a question: can the opponent remove fewer than k edges? For example, the player can choose the tree {AD, BD, BC} on the first move. If the opponent has to remove 2 edges, then those edges are AD and BD. After that the player adds the edge CD, which results in the tree of weight 11. But if the opponent can remove fewer than 2 edges, the edge removed is AD. Then the player can't add the edge CD, as it'd produce a cycle, the only option is the edge AB. This results in the tree of weight 10.

Yes. The formula says it's less than or equal to k. Also, the edges that can be deleted by the adversary are not necessarily those in the first stage solution,  which means edge can be deleted from the graph G. so for tree {AD, BD, BC}, the best remove is AD and AB results weight 7
